# ruby on rails pass a value to .last()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to ruby on rails, so I'm probably missing some syntax. Big picture I am trying to get the value for a specified percentile. Conceptually I am taking my table 'Scores', sorting it, getting the last 'x' values, and then taking the first value. I can't seem to figure out how to pass 'x', which is based on the length of the dataset to the chain.

```
def get_percentile()
  record_count = Scores.count(:id)*0.05
  record_threshold = record_count.round()
  Score_percentile = Scores.order(:points).last(record_threshold).first().points
  return Score_percentile
end
get_percentile
```

If I just enter .last(20) this works as I expect, so I just don't know how to pass the variable.
Thanks.

Comment: Sadly no. I was simplifying it and missed changing that. It's changed now.

Comment: And you're absolutely sure your model class is `Scores` and not `Score`? Model names tend to be singular.

Comment: The actual model is Signup. I changed it and simplified it. It runs just fine if I do `Signup.order(:points).last(20).first().points` instead of a variable name.

Comment: You might want to try `ceil()` instead of `round()`. You might be getting `last(0)`. The ceil function rounds up. 0.05 => 1

Comment: Thank you. ceil() instead of round fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be passing a `0` into your `.last()` function with your rounding.

There are a variety of options to make sure you pass at least a `1`

`[record_threshold, 1].max` will give you at least 1. https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max

Changing `.round()` to `.ceil()` rounds up in all instances. https://apidock.com/ruby/Float/ceil

Comment: Thank you -- I'll use [record_threshold, 1].max to make sure I don't end up with 0 record.